# Is it possible to bundle/ship PHP+MySQL in standalone executable?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I am trying to create an application that has a sender and receiver. The entire application is only meant to be used on a LAN and can also possibly be done almost completely through the browser.

The "sender" part is an application of some sort that will need to run a local server on the person's computer and allow for php,html,css,js, and mysql to run.

On the "receiver" end, it is simply a person's browser accessing a webpage being served up from the "sender" application.

I have been looking into nodejs as a means of accomplishing the server part of this...but I am not sure if I can ship it as an exe with mysql and php installed and allow it to be execd from php. I am aware of being able to install these extensions using npm, but I want to ship a whole exe to the end user and not have them install node on their own.

Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to run PHP and MySQL, Node.js is not a means to do that.

Comment: (I might have overly broadened the title/scope of question; please correct it if I have.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). It appears to be a portable(-ish) installation of Apache, PHP, MySQL, and a few other things (e.g., Perl). You way want to see if you can strip out the irrelevant parts and put your application code into it somehow.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want. Going to check it out and report back. On a totally unrelated note, you wouldn't happen to know how to symlink an assets folder to a folder in the home dir similar to how dropbox works? I want the client to have a dedicated folder for them to drag and drop files they want to share. I am guessing I am going to have to chmod said folder as well to allow non sudo.

Comment: I don't know how Dropbox works, but you said they symlink, so you should just be able to do that too?

Comment: Ok xampp is awesome...but I dont know if I can have ffmpeg installed on it with its dependencies...any ideas? Need to use ffmpeg to convert video files from php

Comment: Assuming you're on Windows, you may be able to include the binaries from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Check the licensing on that; if it's GPL, you'll need to give them the sources, too. (Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a sure way to this.

I came across server2go some few months ago and it does the work perfectly.
Just download server2go from here http://www.server2go-web.de/download/download.html

Run the application and a folder will be created to the location specified with all the needed files in it.

Just copy your php, html, css etc files to the www folder

Import your mysql database if you are using mysql

When all is set, zip the folder and then use 
zipInstaller, you can get it here http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/zipinst.html

ZipInstaller creates an exe application.

Thanks